# I have trouble to use props, and state value in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

in CurrnetSensor component, i make state value.
but I can't use this.state.zoneID  and  this.props.zoneID

how can get fix zoneID in currentSensor component?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRCiB.png)

In mainPage.tsx

```
<div>
    <CurrentSensor zoneID="101"/>
</div>
```

In currentSensor.tsx

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        zones: state.zoneMap.zones,
        selectZone: state.zoneMap.selectZone,

    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {};
}

const connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>;

class CurrentSensor extends React.Component<PropsFromRedux> {
    constructor(Props) {
        super(Props);
        this.state = {
            zoneID: Props.zoneID,
        };
        this.container = React.createRef();
    
    }

    this.state.zoneID  //error. i can't use!
    this.props.zoneID  //error. i can't use!
}
```

Comment: I guess you can use them under lifecycle functions... not randomly in the class, since they depend on react updates...  Have you tried to use them in render for example?